# How to determine if all carbon atoms in a cyclic compound lie on the same plane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I'm currently doing a-levels chemistry and came across a question asking if all 17 carbon atoms in cyclic rings of a cholesterol molecule lie on the same plane. I've done some googling and it turns out that they do not lie on the same plane, but I could not find an explanation for this. Could anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: It's rather opposite, atoms aren't in the same plane unless there's a good reason for that.

Comment: [This](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~urdesai/intro.htm#Structure) isn't a bad reference. Some suspects are lower-energy conformations of the fused rings (cis- or trans-fused) as well as boat/chair energetic favorability.